# What is the order of magnitude of C# String.Replace()

Tags: .net, replace, big-o

Just as simple as the subject. What is the complexity order of magnitude (Big O notation) of the String.Replace(char, char) and String.Replace(string, string) methods in C# / VB .Net

Ideally I think the complexity should be O(N) and O(N log N) maybe O(N^2) respectively, but I cannot find any documentation to that effect.

Comment: There is no special magic, the processor has to look at every character in the string to find a possible match.  And it has to copy every character to create the new string.  It is fundamental O(n).

Comment: @HansPassant, that's true only for (char, char) method. But in the case of (string, string) searching for a sequence in an array isn't O(n)

Comment: Google "boyer-moore search" for an example algorithm.

Comment: There's nothing specified in the documentation, so there's nothing *contractual*. That being said, *an* implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp#L582)

Comment: In general string search is O(N * M) in the worst case and O(N+M) in the best case, where N and M are the string lengths.

I'm speculating but I would think using the O(N*M) as a basis for calculation would be relatively safe in the case of the C# implementation.

Comment: @MikeDinescu,  good comment. However, I think best case would be O(N) where string M isn't found.